# How to check if a specific application is using the Nvidia GPU or the internal GPU

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

In the Windows task manager there used to be a specific columns for the GPU (as shown in the below image) showing which applications are using the Dedicated GPU (Nvidia) and which applications are only using the internal GPU or the CPU.

[image]

***Is there a similar task manager which can show the GPU and the CPU processes at the same time like the windows task manager in Ubuntu 20.04  ?***

Comment: I bumped into [NVTOP](https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop) a while back, but haven't yet used it. I do use `sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia*` now and then. I'm pretty sure I got both from this site and that this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Check `nvidia-smi` or `gpustat` (I prefer the latter).

Comment: @KGIII .. nvtop works fine ... Still HTOP shows the CPU status and NVTOP shows the GPU stats .. Why is it that in Ubuntu both the CPU and the GPU processes cannot be seen in the same application, like in Windows ?

Comment: Probably because nobody has yet authored such a tool that differentiates while showing all the running processes. It does sound like a useful application and there's some demand for said application as I see your question pop up fairly regularly. If you're a programmer, get to it. I'm not a programmer, or at least not a very good one.